# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install Tensorflow in my PC, i installed Python 3.5.2 64-bit, cuda_8.0.61 for windows 10 and cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0

I used "native" pip to install GPU version of Tensorflow, then i open IDLE and testing with "import tensorflow as tf" and i got the error bellow

### How can i fix this ? Thanks you in advance <3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue installing Tensorflow -- not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to run Tensorflow on Windows following these steps. Hope it helps! It may change depending in which folder you installed Python.

1. Download and install Python 3.5.x
2. Download and install Nvidia CUDA Toolkit
3. Download CuDNN 5.1
4. Copy CuDNN files to Nvidia CUDA toolkit folder when 2. has completed (usually is located on C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0)

   - copy cudnn\bin\cudnn64_5.dll to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\
   - copy cudnn\include\cudnn.h   to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include\
   - copy cudnn\lib\x64\cudnn.lib to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\
5. Install Tensorflow via pip command prompt
   'pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu'

   5.1 TensorFlow dependencies

   - make sure that Visual C++ Redistributate 2015 x64 is installed. If not, download it
   - move _curses_curses.cp35-win_amd64.pyd and _curses_panel.cp35-win_amd64.pyd to
      C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages (or you may need to download them as the next packages. just Ctrl+f for 'curses')
   - download and install these packages via pip (move to the directory where they were
      downloaded, open a command prompt and make 'pip install package_name')

     - numpy+mkl (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

       - download numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
       - pip install numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
     - scipy (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

       - download scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
       - pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
   - open command prompt and make 'pip install matplotlib'

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

to install tensorflow instead of:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the accepted one.  It wouldn't let me edit the typo because "Edits must be at least 6 characters".  What a silly policy, shame on stackoverflow.

Comment: This does not work for windows. It says tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not for windows

Answer (score 4):

My computer is Windows with CPU and I have had same issues. I uninstall tensorflow 1.9 and install 1.5 instead. It works right now.

Comment: Worked for me. Here is the command: pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0

Answer (score 4):

**Why don't try Anaconda?**

```
conda create -n gpu_env tensorflow-gpu
conda activate gpu_env
```

As easy as that. All the packages and runtime needed (Visual Studio included) will be brought together while you watch in awe :). **Give it a try!**

**Caveat:** You need to run Keras from inside tensorflow **in order for it to detect and use your GPU**. Otherwise if you use just keras and tensorflow as a backend, **Keras will use plain tensorflow and not tensorflow-gpu**. Boths are installed side by side.

Meaning you should code it this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models       import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers       import Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks    import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping,CSVLogger
from tensorflow.keras.utils        import plot_model
.............
.............
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I saw issues on GitHub too, many guys struggle with it. I think anyone install Python with Anaconda should install tensorflow-gpu by conda command. That's much more compatible and messed up issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists check the version numbering and make sure cuda and TF are compatible.

[Check the version numbering here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

or for a **simpler** way, use Anaconda

```html
conda create --name new_env_name tensorflow-gpu
activate new_env_name
```

*I successfully installed TensorFlow GPU version 1.12 (latest until the date of writing) with Cuda 9.0, GeForce 1050 Ti, Windows 10 and Python 3.6.7*

Note: You have installed the CUDA Toolkit (version 9) for TensorFlow to recognize your GPU

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was with a package named protobuf, It was solved by using 
`pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`
which upgraded protobuf to 3.6.1 and solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

Everything could be installed from the console:

```
conda create --name tf-gpu
conda install -c aaronzs tensorflow-gpu
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn
conda install keras-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you.
The problem is that Anaconda automatically updates the python version when installing ipython and spyder, which becomes version 3.6.
You can change the python version to version 3.5 by entering the tensorflow environment via Anaconda.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQHc9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let’s solve this issue in a simplified way…

I do hope that you are going through some problems when trying to import TensorFlow or maybe when importing other libraries which use TensorFlow in the backend.

I solved the above problem by installing Visual C++ distribution.

[Click to download visual C++ version](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe).

Now, It ran successfully.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.