# Installing Tensorflow with Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on Python and wanted to install Tensorflow to play with some machine learning stuff. I followed the steps in this link `https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows`. However I got the error during import when I run the validate program. 
I am not sure what happened, thank you for your help.

> ErrorDuringImport: problem in tensorflow - ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 994, in _gcd_import File "", line 971, in _find_and_load File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 658, in _load_unlocked File "", line 571, in module_from_spec File "", line 922, in create_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File "D:\Work\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV6aK.png)

Comment: Is it installed successfully? Check by running `pip list`

Comment: yes, tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0 is shown in command prompt

Comment: I guess this is the same issue, try the steps suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942185/failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime-python-3-5-2

Comment: Solved! Thanks mate!

Comment: anytime! @Calvin