# Error while import tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I was working with tensorflow and keras for a while, and I was using tensorflow==1.4.1 version with CUDA toolkit 8.0 and cudnn 5.1 and it was working perfectly fine. But recently I wanted to install tensorforce, which requires me to install tensorflow 1.5 +
So I decided to install lates tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0 as well as CUDA toolkit 9.0 and 7.0.5 cudnn from nvidia's website. And as always I followed steps in official tensorflow documentation for installing tensorflow on windows. But I ended up getting this error when trying to import tensorflow. I have seen similar quetions, suggesting to install MS Visual Studio 2015, but it didn't work for me
I tried uninstalling and installing again a couple of times. But unsuccefully.

Here is my set up:
Windows 10
tensorflow-gpu == 1.8.0
CUDA toolkit 9.0
CUDNN 7.0.5 (also tried using Cudnn 7.1)
virtual conda env with python 3.6.3
installed by: pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

And I found a similar question which also hasn't been answered:
[Error while importing TensorFlow 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259280/error-while-importing-tensorflow-1-8#new-answer)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your CPU is a bit old and doesn't support AVX. Prebuilt binaries require AVX since TF 1.6, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-with-no-gpu/50434293#50434293).

Try and see if installing TF 1.5 (without AVX but supported by tensorforce) solves your problem. (You will obviously need to change the CUDA & CuDNN version again to match TF 1.5's requirements).

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast! Actually it is quite likely, since on my laptop I installed tensorflow successfully without any problems, my laptop cpu is core i7 4500U. So I will try it out.

Comment: Thank you again! I have spent a couple of days on this problem. But now It workes!