# Installing Tensorflow, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have tried for so long to try and install this properly but I can't get it to work, and I have looked around for help. So I have it 'installed' but when i try this

```
import tensorflow
```

I get this huge error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "D:\Python\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WHATEVERS\characters\sPEECHRECOG.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "D:\Python\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I've  tried re-installing it and updating it and installing some visual studio thing but nothing works, when i try installing it it says 'requirement already satisfied'

Please help tensorflow is crucial to what im working on

Comment: Could you post your HW setup, OS, and specify what 'some visual studio thing' is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue installing Tensorflow with no GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-with-no-gpu)

Comment: What is HW? I'm on windows 10 and I saw somewhere said you had to install Visual Studio 15 but that didnt fix it @DocDriven

Comment: HW = hardware, mainly which graphics card so that we can tackle possble problems concerning CUDA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conda, it can provide an independent python environment. And then try install tensorflow again .

Comment: So I installed anaconda, did conda install tensorflow, it said it downloaded but when i go onto my python project it says no module named tensorflow

Comment: @MiniMiloe 
You need to activate the environment. 
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html
conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
activate tensorflow