# Tensorflow - ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, importerror

I am having some issue importing Tensorflow-CPU.

When I import `import tensorflow as tf`, I get this error

```
MYPC@MYPC-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I am using:

OS: `Windows 7 x64`
Python: `3.5.4`

I have install tensorflow by using : `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`.
I think tensorflow version is 1.10.x which I installed.

Can this error be fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had the exact same problem :). Weird question but, what CPU are you using?

Comment: Intel(R) core(TM) i3 550

Answer (score 2):

It may appear that your CPU is missing AVX instructions.

I wrote a guide on how to fix this problem, for future reference.

https://github.com/tintinmovie/Guides_and_Solutions/blob/master/Tensorflow%20-%20No%20module%20named%20'_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'.md

Hopefully you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue?answertab=votes#answer-50434293). I had this issue because maybe I am using old cpu `Intel(R) core(TM) i3`.

I solved my problem by using `pip uninstall tensorflow` and installing old version of `pip install tensorflow==1.5`.

Comment: Installing older versions of tensorflow, is still not recommend as each new update brings new patches and features.