# Facing Issues while importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow. I have installed tensorflow. But while i am executing below query:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I am getting below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
swig_import_helper()
 13         try:
  ---> 14             return importlib.import_module(mname)
 15         except ImportError:

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, 
 package)
  125             level += 1
  --> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  127 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, 
 package, level)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
 _find_and_load(name, import_)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
 _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
 _load_unlocked(spec)

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
  module_from_spec(spec)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in 
 create_module(self, spec)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in 
 _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
 57 
 ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
 59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
 16             return 
 importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
 ---> 17     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
 18     del swig_import_helper

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
 swig_import_helper()
 15         except ImportError:
 ---> 16             return 
 importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
 17     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, 
 package)
 125             level += 1
 --> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 127 

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-2-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
  ----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in 
  <module>()
   20 
   21 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
   ---> 22 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
   disable=unused-import
   23 
   24 try:

   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py 
   in <module>()
   47 import numpy as np
   48 
   ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
   50 
   51 # Protocol buffers

   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
   72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
   73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % 
   traceback.format_exc()
    ---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
   75 
   76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-
   import,line-too-long

    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in 
    swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in 
    _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in 
    create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
    _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in 
    <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in 
    swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

   See
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

```
   for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
   above this error message when asking for help.
```

I searched in Google , but i could not find the exact solution . Could anyone please help me . I am using `Python 3.6.4` version.

Comment: How did you install it (conda, pip, pip3, apt)? And which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: I tried conda, pip both. But not getting output.

Comment: Did you try this in an environment then?

Comment: In Conda, ** Preparing Transaction : done,Verifying Transaction : done,Executing Transaction: failed** .. I don't know what to do now .

Comment: Can you please post the exact stack of commands that you executed before trying to import tensorflow? And still, what tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: I ran **conda install tensorflow** command. Version is 1.10.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue installing Tensorflow -- not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU is older to support AVX instructions...
Use an official pre-built binary of TF 1.5 or earlier.

complete answers are in this issue..

[Issue installing Tensorflow -- not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue)