# ImportError when trying to execute `import tensorflow as tf`

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I get an ImportError when trying to execute `import tensorflow as tf`. I am using a SIMATIC ET 200SP on Windows 10. But works with version 1.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) 
File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') 
File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/setup/opencontroller/add_two_numbers_via_TensorFlow.py", line 3, in <module> import tensorflow as tf 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module> raise ImportError(msg) 

ImportError: 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) 
File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen. 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') 
File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Comment: Greetings, welcome to SO.  Please realize that a dump of a stacktrace, without formatting is *almost* useless, most readers will just bypass the question.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue installing Tensorflow -- not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue)