# Can't import tensorflow in spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

When I try to import tensorflow in Spyder I get this error,

> import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>
> File
>   "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line
>   27, in 
>       from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio
>
> File
>   "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2\audio__init__.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
>
> File
>   "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File
>   "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line
>   242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\packages\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

I have tried these from anaconda prompt

> conda create -n tfp python=3.6
>
> activate tfp
>
> conda install tensorflow
>
> python

In which case "import tensorflow as tf" works.
However, still not in Spyder.

I also tried

> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

But that gives the error,

> tensorflow-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Also the "spyder" command gvies the error,

> 'spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your CPU support AVX instructions? Or have you installed Microsoft Redistributable C++ 2015 Update 3?

Comment: Did you try the solutions suggested in [Issue installing Tensorflow — not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50430086/7306999)?

Comment: @Xukrao I am trying the suggestion in your link, but "pip uninstall tensorflow" has been hanging for over two hours in spyder with nothing happening and no output. My machine is about 8 years old maybe it doesn't meet required spec?

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue by installing spyder in the conda environment "conda install spyder" and running it from there. Though I think this is older version of tensorflow which results in other issues.