# What's the problem of 'error code 3221225501' during running tensorflow codes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to run the keras codes with tensorflow backend. But it caused "ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501". It seems not sloved by others..

I just install python 3.7.4  in CPU enviroment and install the tensorflow with edition:tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl. And it is sucessfully installed. When I run my code, errors occours: ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501. I search the problem on internet, and lower down the tensorflow edition with 1.12.0 and download the files from github. It seems useless. So I come here for help. 
Hope someone can provide a good suggestion, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your CPU supports AVX Instructions.

If it does not support AVX instructions, then you should use TF version 1.5 or earlier versions.

From TF 1.6 and above, TF binaries uses AVX instructions.

Please refer to below link for more information.

[Issue installing Tensorflow -- not a CUDA/CuDNN issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430086/issue-installing-tensorflow-not-a-cuda-cudnn-issue?answertab=votes#answer-50434293)

Comment: Thanks.. Later, I reinstalled the keras, it seems problem being caused by edition incompability. I have solved it by installing correct revision.