# Problem in importing tensorflow using command prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\varsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\varsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\varsh\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\varsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\varsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any research? This error seems to be quite common, so you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. Python 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942185/failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime-python-3-5-2)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to show if tensorflow is properly installed using :

```
pip show tensorflow
```

U will get an output like :

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.1.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
```

If you don't get any output it may not be properly installed.

Try uninstalling using :

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

And try installing again.