# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am getting below error while doing `from keras.models import Sequential`

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> 82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
> ---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
> 84
> 85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\joe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Here is the result of `pip freeze`

```
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.9.12
anaconda-project==0.8.3
....
conda==4.9.2
conda-build==3.18.11
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/keras-applications_1594366238411/work
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
tensorflow==2.3.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
```

Per answer at [Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. Python 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942185/failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime-python-3-5-2) I tried below

```
conda create -n gpu_env tensorflow-gpu
conda activate gpu_env
```

Which gives below result on `pip freeze`

```
jupyter-core==4.6.3
Keras-Applications @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/keras-applications_1594366238411/work
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
```

But when I open the jupyter notebook and execute the program get the same error.Not sure what's the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using Anaconda it will support

## Tensorflow == 2.1.0

## Keras == 2.3.1

create a new environment for tensorflow

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
activate tf
```

then install keras

```
pip install keras==2.3.1
```